# Casting Generic Type then Using Ref

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, generics

I need some clarity for my problem.

I have a method which does this:

```
public static void SetEntityValue<TEntity>(ref TEntity entityToTransform, PropertyHelper entityProperty)
{
   // create type from entity
   Type t = entityToTransform.GetType();
   // get the property to set
   var prop = t.GetProperty(entityProperty.Name);
   // set the property value to the one parsed
   prop.SetValue(entityToTransform, entityProperty.Value, null);
}
```

The `PropertyHelper` just contains two properties, Name and Value.

So, I have a method that takes an Generic Type and then needs to initialise a new one and fill its properties with values, will this method do that:

```
TEntity ReadIntoEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity, XElement node)
{
    if (!node.HasElements)
        throw new IllFormedDocumentException("Entity found but contains no properties");

    var xmlProps = node.Elements();

    Type t1 = entity.GetType();

    // the line which initialises a new TEntity same as string myString = new string();
    TEntity newEntity = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();

    var props = t1.GetProperties();
    var readableProps = props.Select(x => new PropertyHelper(GenericHelper.GetEntityProperty(x), GenericHelper.GetEntityValueAsObject<TEntity>(entity, x)));

    List<string> foundAProp = new List<string>();

    foreach (var el in xmlProps)
    {
        // iterate through all xml elements

        foreach (var prop in readableProps)
        {
            // check the prop exists in the xml set

            // We found a prop that exists!
            if (el.Name.ToString() == prop.Name.ToString())
            {
                foundAProp.Add(prop.Name.ToString());

                GenericHelper.SetEntityValue<TEntity>(ref newEntity, prop);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Will this work like Non Generics would do:

```
MyEntity ReadIntoEntity(XElement node)
{
    if (!node.HasElements)
        throw new IllFormedDocumentException("Entity found but contains no properties");

    var xmlProps = node.Elements();

    MyEntity newEntity = new MyEntity();

    var props = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties();
    var readableProps = props.Select(x => new PropertyHelper(GenericHelper.GetEntityProperty(x), GenericHelper.GetEntityValueAsObject<TEntity>(entity, x)));

    List<string> foundAProp = new List<string>();

    foreach (var el in xmlProps)
    {
        // iterate through all xml elements

        foreach (var prop in readableProps)
        {
            // check the prop exists in the xml set

            // We found a prop that exists!
            if (el.Name.ToString() == prop.Name.ToString())
            {
                foundAProp.Add(prop.Name.ToString());

                GenericHelper.SetEntityValue<MyEntity>(ref newEntity, prop);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So Effectively is:

```
TEntity newEntity = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
```

Equivalent to this:

```
MyEntity newEntity = new MyEntity();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will that method do the thing? Try it and see.

However:

```
TEntity newEntity = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
```

should be replaced with

```
TEntity newEntity = new TEntity();
```

after adding the `new()` generic constraint for the parameter. This will add compile time checks to ensure that the entity has a valid parameterless constructor. I.e.:

```
TEntity ReadIntoEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity, XElement node)
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    // ...
```

And you don't need `ref` in your first method, assuming all your entities are `class` types.

Comment: so what does the where clause mean? and then the : class, new() mean?

Comment: It's a generic constraint that specifies that when calling the method, the `TEntity` type may only be a reference (`class`) type with a parameterless constructor. Read all about constrations at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: What do you mean "how do you call it"? You call it just like any other method you've undoubtedly done thousands of times already.

Comment: I was getting an error, and I think that is because my entites don't have a the new constructor, however I'm passing through all generics, so why am I getting this error?!

Comment: If you're getting an error, you could at least post it. Just saying "I'm getting an error" isn't very helpful. If your entities don't have a parameterless constructor, `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` isn't going to work either.

Comment: 'TEntity' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless in order to use it as a parameter 'TEntity' in method. This is strange because it isn't going to know until TEntity is actually passed.

Comment: Add that error and the line you're calling the method from into your original post.